# How to make Google map fill available height between dynamic header and footer

Tags: html, css, google-maps, flexbox

I have a header and footer, each with dynamic content. This is actually an aspx page with a master page which contains header/footer content which may vary in size.  I can not enforce a px height for header or footer as they may have images or just text, etc.  I want to make the Google map fill the available page height (and width) between them.  I'll give the map canvas a minimum height of say 200px, just in case, but otherwise it should force the footer to bottom of the page without scrolling (unless the screen is short enough for the 200px minimum to require scrolling).

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">Title<br />of<br />variable<br/>height</div>
    <div id="body">
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        Footer<br />of<br />variable<br />height
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a Fiddle showing it very close using flex approach... It seems to work in Chrome/FireFox but this does not work in IE11.
https://jsfiddle.net/randbrown/7dc8u6ja/4/

Is the flex-based approach best for this and if so what am I missing to get it working in IE?  Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working in IE11.  It needed height:100% on the #wrapper div.  Now it works on Chrome/Firefox/IE11/Edge.

```
height: 100%;
```

Updated fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/7dc8u6ja/5/